# escape quotes and @ in web.configs

Tags: c#, web-config

Hi i'm trying to get the following back from the web.config

@"Chief\adama";

and will use it as follows:

```
var queuePath = @"Chief\adama";
```

at the moment i have:

```
 <add key="AdamaPath" value="@Chief\adama" />
```

it is actually only the Chief part which will change and i have tried the following:

web.config:

```
<add key="AdamaPath" value="Chief" />
```

.cs:

```
var machine = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdamaPath"];
var queuePath = "@" + "\"" + machine + "\adama" + "\"";
```

but i get:
"@ \"Chief\adama\""

I have also tried:

```
 <add key="AdamaPath" value="@ &quot; Chief\adama &quot;" />
```

which also gets:

"@ \" Chief\adama \""

can anyone let me know how to get rid of the extra " and \ 
thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a `@` for _inside_ the string?

Comment: i am using this to access msmq so its a path to a public queue on a remote server - the @ should not be inside the quotes

Comment: And what exact output do you need? What's the end result that you want?

Comment: if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queuePath))
                {
                    MessageQueue.Create(queuePath);
                }

Comment: Yes, but what do you need `queuPath` to be? Exactly? It is really not clear from the question.

Comment: when i hard code it is fine but the remote machine name can change which is why i want to put it in the config

Comment: I'll try again. Which of these should it end up being? `@Chief\adama`? `Chief\adama`? `Chief\@adama`? Something else?

Comment: this one @"Chief\adama";

Comment: No, it doesn't. The `@` is only something that you can do with [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx). You are _constructing_ a string. The _contents_ of the string would be `Chief\adama` (from your last comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is probably all you need:

```
<add key="AdamaPath" value="Chief" />

var machine = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdamaPath"];
var queuePath = machine + "\\adama";
```

The above will produce a string containing `Chief\adama`, which seems to be what you need.

The `@` signifies a verbatim string literal (when preceding a string literal) - you are constructing strings that *contain* this, which can't work as it is a C# features and needs to *precede* string *literals*.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are possibly confusing escape characters for actual string characters. If you just want to pull the value from the `web.config` do:

```
var machine = ConfigurationMananger.AppSettings["AdamaPath"];
var queuePath = String.Format("{0}{1}adama", machine, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

Comment: when i use yourcode i get the following "Chief\\adama" what i need is  @"Chief\adama" any suggestions on that? thanks

Comment: @anna your looking at the value in the watch, `Chief\\adama` is the equivalent to `@"Chief\adama"`. The `@` character basically doesn't process escape characters so it allows you to write characters directly in the string that would usually require escaping.